# Compressing structural information in PDB files

Tags: bioinformatics, pdb, 3d-structure, visualization

There seems to be a lot of redundancy in PDB files.  These files can of course be compressed with general-purpose compression programs like gzip, but I can't help but imagine that these tools are overlooking a significant amount of redundancy in PDB files.  Are there compressors that specifically target PDB files?  If not, what are some aspects of PDB files that are ripe for compression?

Looking at a typical PDB file, some redundancies are immediately apparent.  Other redundancies are less obvious.  Consider this excerpt of two residues from [1MOB](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/1MBO.pdb) (myoglobin):

```
ATOM    332  N   LYS A  42      16.481  27.122 -10.033  1.00 11.15           N  
ATOM    333  CA  LYS A  42      15.926  28.134  -9.159  1.00  8.64           C  
ATOM    334  C   LYS A  42      16.970  29.081  -8.512  1.00 16.74           C  
ATOM    335  O   LYS A  42      16.687  30.075  -7.799  1.00 11.84           O  
ATOM    336  CB  LYS A  42      15.093  27.489  -8.043  1.00 18.03           C  
ATOM    337  CG  LYS A  42      13.731  26.888  -8.502  1.00 19.65           C  
ATOM    338  CD  LYS A  42      12.679  27.912  -8.953  1.00 17.94           C  
ATOM    339  CE  LYS A  42      11.438  27.406  -9.703  1.00 24.82           C  
ATOM    340  NZ  LYS A  42      10.474  28.567  -9.803  1.00 19.81           N  
ATOM    341  N   PHE A  43      18.218  28.599  -8.544  1.00 12.28           N  
ATOM    342  CA  PHE A  43      19.311  29.318  -7.919  1.00 11.81           C  
ATOM    343  C   PHE A  43      20.223  30.024  -8.949  1.00 10.95           C  
ATOM    344  O   PHE A  43      21.201  29.462  -9.450  1.00 10.08           O  
ATOM    345  CB  PHE A  43      20.138  28.301  -7.137  1.00  9.30           C  
ATOM    346  CG  PHE A  43      19.494  27.689  -5.877  1.00  9.53           C  
ATOM    347  CD1 PHE A  43      19.572  28.376  -4.679  1.00 12.01           C  
ATOM    348  CD2 PHE A  43      18.837  26.465  -5.923  1.00 10.54           C  
ATOM    349  CE1 PHE A  43      18.993  27.861  -3.536  1.00  9.59           C  
ATOM    350  CE2 PHE A  43      18.261  25.959  -4.775  1.00  8.62           C  
ATOM    351  CZ  PHE A  43      18.341  26.666  -3.597  1.00  7.89           C
```

These two residues occupy 1,638 bytes as plain text; when compressed with gzip, they occupy 467 bytes.  For reference, the format of ATOM records in PDB files is defined at wwpdb.org/documentation/format33/sect9.html#ATOM.

Almost all of the data in the above excerpt seems redundant.  The first field (ATOM), second field (atom index, e.g. 332 in the first row), sixth field (residue index, e.g. 42), tenth field (occupancy, e.g. 1.00) and last field (element name, e.g. N) seem clearly extraneous.  The fourth field (residue name) could be shortened from three characters to 1 character, or simply an integer.  I'm not a data compression expert, but I imagine gzip picks up most of this redundancy.

Slightly less obviously, the atom names for each residue also seem unnecessary.  To my understanding, the atomic composition of all residues' backbones will always be the same, and represented in PDB files as "N", "CA", "C", "O".  The same for the atomic composition of the residues' respective sidechains: a lysine sidechain will always be "CB", "CG", "CD", "CE", "NZ" and a phenylalanine sidechain will always be "CB", "CG", "CD1", "CD2", "CE1", "CE2", "CZ".

A subtler redundancy, but one that might increase compressibility a lot, seems like it could be in the atomic coordinates themselves.  For example, in the backbone, would it be possible to deduce each residue atom's X, Y and Z coordinates (12 data points: 4 atoms * 3 coordinates) given only their phi, psi and omega [dihedral angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dihedral_angle&oldid=474965018#Dihedral_angles_of_biological_molecules) (3 data points)?  Could applying dihedral angles to atoms within sidechains similarly remove the need to explicitly list the 3D coordinates there?

Could "temperature  factor" (the second to last field in the excerpt) be losslessly removed, or compressed in some non-obvious way?  What are some other possible optimizations that could be used to more efficiently compress PDB files?  Are there any obvious grave performance implications of these various compression techniques on the speed of a hypothetical decompressor to convert back to the official PDB format?  Have these questions been answered in the literature or an existing PDB-specific compression program?

Thanks in advance for any answers or feedback.

**Edit**:

Given that no PDB-specific file compressors seem to be available, I suppose my specific goal is to develop one.  One potential application I see for this is in significantly decreasing fresh times-to-render in certain use cases of browser-based molecular visualization programs, e.g. [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/), [ChemDoodle Web Components](http://web.chemdoodle.com/) or [GLmol](http://webglmol.sourceforge.jp/glmol/viewer.html).  Another application could be decreasing the time and size of data needed to download archives of PDB files like those described [here](http://www.wwpdb.org/downloads.html).

This would of course require a way to efficiently decompress the packed PDB files, but this trade-off between decompression time and download time seems like it could be useful in at least some niche applications.

**Edit 2**:

In a comment, nico asks "How would compressing the file decrease render time?".  Decreasing gzipped PDB file size (e.g. by half or more) and thus decreasing time needed to download the file would decrease the time between when the PDB file was requested from a remote server and when the structure was rendered by a molecular visualization program running on a client machine. Apologies if that use of "fresh time-to-render" in that context was unclear.

A lossless compression could also involve encoding the PDB file to an object (e.g. JSON) that is faster to parse for the visualization program, and decrease render times that way.  Looking around further, if the application only required displaying the 3D structure and not also retaining data about specific atoms and residues, then using a binary mesh compression (e.g. [webgl-loader](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-loader/)) seems like it would probably decrease time-to-render even more.

Comment: Do you have any specific goal in mind? The size of PDB files shouldn't be a problem today, the largest ones I've seen are only a few megabytes, like e.g. ribosome structures or NMR structures with large bundles. Or is this just an exercise to understand the PDB format better?

Comment: How would compressing the file decrease render time? And, I agree with @Mad Scientist, we are speaking of a few Mb maximum, so building a compressor from scratch would seem only a nice proof of concept

Comment: It sounds to me that apart from the fact that it is PDB files that are under discussion here, this is not really a biology question per se but more of a programming question and you are likely to get better responses from that forum.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I asked my original questions to get answers from people knowledgeable in the domain of structural biology on what information in PDB files is redundant and can expressed more compactly.  In addition to providing answers about that, respondents have asked some reasonable questions that were unrelated to the structural biology, and I've answered in kind in my edits.  I would have asked in [Bioinformatics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6729/bioinformatics), but that forum is still just a proposal.

Comment: finally, 5 years later, [bioinformatics.SE got into private beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics), but it may get closed if it doesn't get more Q&A in the next few days. Structural bioinformatics is underrepresented there, so consider supporting that site by asking a question there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making a few assumptions that are likely not valid for all PDB files. For example:

- Residue indices are not necessarily sequential, nor do they have to start at 1
- Not all possible residues have 1-letter code equivalents, there are thousands of possible exotic residues, not only the standard amino acids
- PDB files are not only used for proteins, but also nucleic acids and small molecules (usually as ligands)
- Occupancy can be different from 1.0 if there are multiple conformations represented in the PDB file
- The element type is obvious for unmodified amino acids and nucleotides, but not necessarily for more exotic residues (though usually it's easy to identify)
- The distances between atoms are not necessarily the ideal distances, so you would need angles and distances to represent the coordinates.

The temperature factor is an experimentally determined value, there is no obvious compression for that. You can safely discard it if you don't need that data, and e.g. it has no meaning anyway in NMR structures.

The advantage of the PDB format is that pretty much every program can (theoretically) handle it, though the implementations vary and subtle incompatibilities can cause a lot of headaches. The size of PDB files is almost never a problem, so there is no significant motivation to improve on the format in that regard.

Comment: Those are good points about A) needing not only dihedral angles but also distances between each atom and B) temperature factor being extraneous in NMR structures.  

I think the usefulness of compressing PDB files is probably best suited for a separate discussion, but I appreciate this answer.  Definitely informative.

Answer (score 3):

The PDB file format was specified in the dawn of computing to fit on punch cards. So it has some shortcomings that have led to generations of scientists cursing the fixed-width column format. By now, it has been superseded by an XML-like format: PDBML. Of course XML is less space-efficient than a column layout, so you can see that disk space was not the main concern, but being able to parse the files. Nonetheless, the [PDBML page](http://pdbml.pdb.org/) states that they offer three types of download files: "fully marked-up files, files without atom records, files with a more space efficient encoding of atom records" -- so you could check what they do in the latter case.

As for your suggestions: in theory you could use only dihedral angles. However, the numerical errors would accumulate as you go along re-constructing the 3D coordinates, and different software architectures will give you different precision. So: explicit is better than implicit in scientific file formats.

Answer (score 3):

I'm resurecting an old question, but I've heard this question from a few young bioinformaticians and had a couple more points to consider about compressing PDB files.

The first is that many PDB files (including all PDBs hosted on the PDB site) have some 300-400 lines of meta data at the top of the file.  This accounts for about 10-20% of the total file size.  Also many PDBs have ANISOU records, but they're about as redundant.

Second, even if you're dealing with raw coordinate data, I think you're underestimating just how well GZIP already does.  Let's just say half that column data is somehow completely redundant and we can just compress it all away. Next we'll encode the 5 numbers (x, y, z, q, b) in binary using 2 bytes for each number (which isn't even enough room for practical use, but we're optimistic here).  So we've compressed 80 columns to 10 columns, which is 12.5% of the original size. Running gzip on a couple simple pdbs (after grepping out just the ATOM records), it achieves 23.0% of the original size. If we really cared about file size, we could use bzip2 which gets to 16.4%.

Our magical compression tool is only twice as good as gzip, which is nice, but gzip is already four times better than uncompressed pdbs.  If we cared enough, we'd just use bzip2, which is only 30% larger than this hypothetical minimum size. And once we got all the atom specifications back in there, I'm sure they'd be virtually identical.  The bottom line is that bzip2 is already very close to the maximal theoretical compression limit for many kinds of files, especially text files. For genome sequencing data, which is orders of magnitude larger and more redundant, people just made slight modifications of the underlying algorithm.

I've downloaded and analyzed the entire PDB database (a little out of date, but it's 75K structures and 14GB, gzip compressed), and can appreciate wanting to shrink it down further, believe me.  At that level, compression makes a difference in analysis time just reading data off the hard disk (or an NFS server). Fortunately, many (if not most) pdb tools read gzip'd pdbs natively (sadly not the case for bzip'd files). Perl, Python, and every other major bioinformatics language have simple APIs for automatically decompressing gzip'd files as they're opened. Against the ubiquity of gzip, it's not really worth thinking about a small improvement in compression. Again, if we cared, we'd just make everything use bzip2 instead.

The future is more like PDBML, which I kind of despise.  But it's far more complete and easier to parse (given that XML parsers exist for every major language), even if the files themselves are an order of magnitude larger. I don't like them (and mostly XML in general) because they're not human readable in any practical sense. But at the same time I'm not suggesting we just move to a 120 column PDB format just to address PDB format limitations.

Using only dihedral angles would never work either, and not because of numerical precision. There is small but significant variance in bond lengths and angles that would cause coordinates to be off by angstroms by the end of the chain.  It wouldn't help with ANISOU, REMARK, and other records. And it would frankly be a huge pain to write new parsers for.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old, but for the record: the RCSB PDB is currently working on a project to compress the PDB structural data with a new file format, called MMTF (MacroMolecular Transmission Format).

The format uses MessagePack for serialization and does custom compression, achieving ~ 5x advantage over mmCIF gzipped files. Currently the whole PDB archive fits into 7GB. Most importantly parsing time is reduced dramatically thanks to the format being binary.

You can read everything about it at the website: http://mmtf.rcsb.org

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer, yes?

Comment: @VanceLAlbaugh reading the original post, one of the questions was "Are there compressors that specifically target PDB files?". I'm answering directly to that, only a few years later...